# Adjust text positioning within a Lightning Component on record page

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a simple lightning component that I'm displaying on an opportunity record page and I'm using the component set visibility filters to show or hide the component if the filter criteria is met. I've positioned the component at the top of the record page and I'm trying to adjust the positioning of the text inside the component. I'm using the style:

`.THIS { width: 100%; }`

So, the component expands the full width of the window. The text is aligned to the left.

Here is the component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
    <div class="slds-notify slds-notify_toast slds-theme_error">
        <div class="slds-notify__content">
            <h2 class="slds-text-heading_small slds-align_absolute-center">Message Title Goes Here!!</h2>
            <br/>
            <p class="slds-align_absolute-center">My Message Body Goes Here!!</p>                
        </div>
    </div>  
</aura:component>
```

I'd like to align the text to be centered across the full width of the component. I've tried using `text-align: center;` and adjusting the margins, but the text does not adjust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason for the styling to get overridden is `slds-notify_toast` class. From your question, it appears it dont want to show as toast. Ideally, even if you want to show toast you should be using [lightning:notificationsLibrary](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:notificationsLibrary/documentation).

However, if you dont want toast, then remove `slds-notify_toast` and use `slds-box` instead to get appropriate box with padding.

```
<div class="slds-notify slds-box slds-theme_error">
    <div class="slds-notify__content">
        <h2 class="slds-text-heading_small slds-align_absolute-center">Message Title Goes Here!!</h2>
        <br/>
        <p class="slds-align_absolute-center">My Message Body Goes Here!!</p>                
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked!